# How to identify an element in selenium even if xpath is same for all the matching nodes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am new to selenium and trying to automate a web application in junit framework. As many get some problem in identifying web elements, I am stuck at a point where two submit buttons are having same xpath

```
//img[@src='https://blrwvmmstst3:8643/madmin/images/icons/add.png']
```

Comment: If you have multiple items with the same XPath 'path' then you can index them with [] operators, but note that XPath is 1-indexed.

Comment: Can you share the html for the page with the two submit buttons? There may be an alternative locator that would be suitable for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can get both with getElements instead of getElement method

or, and thats what id do, try changing the xpath in a way that only the desired submitbutton is returned, for example you could check the buttons id or text